# Factory pattern and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, cross-platform, multiple-inheritance, factory

This is in C++:

Suppose i have a `Control` class, that has virtual methods and has two implementations, a Windows and a Linux one. With a `CreateControl()` method i create a `ControlWindows` or `ControlLinux` that is either the Windows or the Linux implementation.

I also have a `Button` class that inherits from `Control`, and `Button` too has two implementations.
This is a simple diagram:

[image: Class diagram] 
However, in the `ButtonWindows` class i need for example to access methods and members defined in the `ControlWindows` class but i can't do it without inheriting directly from `ControlWindows` and thus having a multiple inheritance design. I would then have multiple instances of members of the `Control` class.

It could be solved by using a virtual inheritance, but that would have a performance impact that i'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Why do you need to access members of the ControlWindows class in the ButtonWindows class if the Control and Button classes are suppose to be wrappers?

Comment: @ZacHowland Suppose i have a DoSomething() method that is declared as virtual both in Control and Button. ControlWindows and ButtonWindows define that method. Inside DoSomething() of ButtonWindows i need to also call the DoSomething() from ControlWindows.

Comment: An easier approach may be to simply #ifdef the implementation so you just have Control and Button (with their implementations) and your compiler settings and target platform would determine which way it gets compiled.  Since you are never going to have a situation where the same bytecode is used on both platforms, there isn't a real need to separate the implementations this way.

Comment: @ZacHowland This is true when talking about different OSes, but what if have a DirectX implementation and OpenGL one, and i can choose, on Windows, to either have a DX object or OGL one. This helps reducing code duplication and managing the organization of code and i hope there's a way other than virtual inheritance. Thanks for helping though, i appreciate it!

Comment: #ifdef's can still be used there.  It has been a while, but SDL used to do exactly that.